# HTML 5 video tag, Video start playing after 2-4 seconds on android using Ionic 3

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build app using ionic 3 with feed videos list using HTML5 video tag, and autoplay the video once it is visible at the screen, everything working fine on IOS, but I am facing an issue on android the video start playing after 2-4 seconds, I think the preload='auto' attribute not working as expected on android.

I tried to use all native ionic plugins (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-exoplayer/) instead of html video tag, but those plugins are playing the video on fullscreen, Its impossible to play video inside the screen with ionic native plugins.

I tried to build my own cordova plugin, but that need to learn the native languages and platforms and learn how to overlay a native view in html, which is not easy.

I am trying to solve this issue from 3 month ago with no luck.

here is a simple ionic 3 app that listing 6 videos have the same issue on android: https://github.com/osa-aq/ionic-videos-android.

**Home Page:**

```
<video-box *ngFor=“let video of virtualScroller.viewPortItems” [video]=“video” no-padding>
```

**Video Box Component html view:**

```
<video #videoE id="{{video.id}}" loop preload=“auto" webkit-playsinline=“webkit-playsinline” class=“videoPlayer”>
```

**Video Box Component ts code:**

```
playVideo(video) {
   this.videoEl.nativeElement.classList.add("open");
   this.videoEl.nativeElement.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem by removing the crosswalk, The video delay before playing on android is caused by crosswalk, Hopefully this will help others

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code in [your home.ts](https://github.com/osa-aq/ionic-videos-android/blob/cc3fe1b398b363d7f66986039c1de83fedcd5fdf/src/pages/home/home.ts), 
Try this:

```
playVideo(video) {
   this.videoEl.nativeElement.classList.add("open");
   this.videoEl.nativeElement.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
     this.videoEl.nativeElement.play();
   }, true);
}
```

Comment: This will not playing the video, The seeked event occurs when the user is finished moving/skipping to a new position in the video

Comment: How about "canplay" event? As far as see your code, there is no event listener.